# Sorting an ArrayList

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Based on my [**previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527230/c-sorting-an-arraylist-of-strings), I've trying now to have them in the following order using the same approach, `OrderByDescending` and `ThenBy`

Original (can be in any random order):

```
1:1
0:0
0:1
2:1
1:0
2:0
```

Output

```
2:0 
1:0 
0:0 
2:1 
1:1 
0:1
```

as you can see, a is `descending`, and b being `ascending`. But I'm still not getting the right sort. Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: I would first Accept the most helpful answer in your first question then ask nicely in a comment for the author of that answer to have a look in this new question. If this one is closely related to the first, you can edit your first question with this and Delete this one.

Comment: At least quote the relevant part(s) from your previous question _and_ add a link to it. We're not doing sequels here.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm still new in here :) Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527230/c-sorting-an-arraylist-of-strings

Comment: The solution(s) in the previous question seem easily adaptable to your new sort order - what have you tried?

Comment: Please use `List<string>` not `ArrayList`

Comment: @BrokenGlass: combinations of `orderby parsed.Left/Right descending/ascending, parsed.Right/Left`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think to what you would do manually:

1. First you must sort the values by the 2nd part in ascending order
2. Then you must sort values having the same 2nd part, using the 1st part in descending order

Translated in LINQ it's pretty the same:

```
var sorted = arrayList
.Cast<string>()
.Select(x => x.Split(':'))
.OrderBy(x => x[1])
.ThenByDescending(x => x[0])
.Select(x => x[0] + ":" + x[1]);
```

To clarify a bit more, `ThenBy/ThenByDescending` methods are used to sort elements that are equal in the previous `OrderBy/OrderByDescending`, hence the code :)

Comment: great answer but one thing I'd change is the last select to an Aggregate instead.

Comment: @philip : `Aggregate()` is similar to `Sum()`, it transforms a list to a single element. Here we want a list, we just need to change each element into something else (i.e. projection) and Select() is the right method to use in case of projection :)

Comment: I use it to concatenate strings all the time i.e. - .Aggregate((lhs,rhs) => lhs + ":" + rhs)

Comment: @philip: Oh, you meant **inside** the Select, i.e. `Select(x => x.Aggregate((l, h) => l + ":" + h));` yes, you can also use that even if I prefer `string.Join` for strings. Anyway, in this case there are just 2 little strings then a simple concatenation is more readable IMO.

Comment: Yeah you are right.  If I wanted to output csv then your way doesn't work because the last field should not output the ','...  Which is how I got in the habit of using Aggregate anyway.  Otherwise, your method works fine.  Unless you know of an override to string.Join or concat that can handle the scenario I described? :)

Comment: @philip: actually also `string.Join()` doesn't add the separator after the last field. For string joining `Aggregate()` and `string.Join()` give the same results, peraphs `string.Join` is better because it uses less memory using a `StringBuilder` under the hood and IMO is more readable :)

Comment: I just tested this and I see that it works perfectly! it's a different story with Concat which could be where I got off-track but hey, who cares now that I know that Join does it. :) thanks.

Comment: So just an FYI... I am at work today and I see the real reason for using Aggregate(...).  It still isn't totally necessary but it is much cleaner.  There was a requirement for taking A B C and making A,B,C or A, B, C...  Those all work perfectly fine using string.Join(...).  However, we also need to do something to the fields as well and not just the separator. So an output would be 'A','B','C' or 'A', 'B', 'C'...  So we have an extension method that is called JoinDelimited and you can pass a Separator as well as a Delimiter.

Comment: @phillip: ah, this sounds reasonable :) Just an hint (maybe useless cause I don't know your JoinDelimited impl.): I'd suggest to use a `StringBuilder` instead of multiple string.Concat (or `+`) because due to the immutability of strings you create a new string on each concat, while you don't using StringBuilder. That can really improve performances in case of many concats :)

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayList.ToList().Select(i => { var split = i.Split(":".ToArray(),2));
                                return new { a = Int32.Parse(split[0]),
                                             b = Int32.Parse(split[1}) }; 
                               })
.OrderByDescending(i => i.a)
.ThenBy(i => i.b)
```

From your question it is not clear whether you want the order-by's reversed (just swap them).
Work from there, perhaps rejoining

```
.Select(i => String.Format("{0}:{1}", i.a, i.b));
```

Good luck